# Connection string with %USERPROFILE% to access DB through Box drive

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to make connection from Microsoft Excel to Access database file on Box drive installed on computer. But I am not able to connect to Access DB file.

I want to replace `C:\Users\raghavgupta\` with `%USERPROFILE%` in connection below, but not able to connect and follow the below process. Can you assist me in this?

Here is the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fixed path actually works, try %USERPROFILE%. Keep in mind that `%` may be a special character in the context you are trying to use it and needs to be escaped.

Comment: I have used %USERPROFILE% not $USERPROFILE$ it was typo mistake here. So i am trying to make connection to access DB through excel query and connection through box drive. So have you any idea?